# How to style lottie file animation to be responsive?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, lottie

Is there a way to style lottie animation to have different width and height based on the screen size?
I use nextjs and I have not been able to style it.

I am trying to have it reduce when it is on a smaller screen, This is my animation component,

```
"use client"
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import AOS from 'aos';
import 'aos/dist/aos.css';
import animationData from '../../public/assets/red.json';
import Lottie from 'react-lottie';

const Call = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    AOS.init({
      duration: 400,
      // Add more enchanting options as needed
    });
  }, []);

  const lottieOptions = {
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    animationData: animationData,
  };

  // Responsive dimensions based on screen width
  const screenWidth = window.innerWidth;

  const calculateDimensions = () => {
    if (screenWidth <= 500) {
      // For small screens, adjust width and height as you desire
      return { width: 200, height: 200 };
    } else {
      // For larger screens, maintain the original dimensions
      return { width: 470, height: 470 };
    }
  };

  const { width, height } = calculateDimensions();

  return (
    <div
      data-aos="fade-up"
      data-aos-offset="100"
      data-aos-easing="ease-in-sine"
      data-aos-delay="50"
      className=""
    >
      <Lottie options={lottieOptions} width={width} height={height} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Call;
```